# How to Remove a Perfectly Good Disk S2D Storage Spaces Direct so it can be used by Operating System?

Tags: storage-spaces-direct

I'm trying to run a Windows Server 2019 Storage Spaces Direct (S2D) cluster with 4 SSDs and 8 spindles per cluster node. There were 2 additional SSDs (1 of which is used for OS, the other is unused at this moment). When setting up the S2D cluster it grabbed all available disk as expected. I went to remove one of the SSDs from the pool and everything seemed to work, however when I ran Get-Disk I could not find the disk I removed from the S2D pool. Below are my steps.

1. Disable auto-pooling

Get-StorageSubSystem Cluster* | Set-StorageHealthSetting -Name "System.Storage.PhysicalDisk.AutoPool.Enabled" -Value False

2. Retire the disks

Get-PhysicalDisk | ? Model -like "*250*" | ? DeviceID -ne 0 | Set-PhysicalDisk -Usage Retired

3. Repair the virtual disks (this is a new cluster so there is only the performance metrics on it)

Get-VirtualDisk | Repair-VirtualDisk -Verbose

4. Check to make sure the job is complete

Get-StorageJob

5. Remove the physical disks

Get-StoragePool S2D* | Remove-PhysicalDisk -PhysicalDisks (Get-PhysicalDisk | ? Model -like "*250*" | ? DeviceID -ne 0)

6. Verify the disks are removed from the pool

Get-StoragePool S2D* | Get-PhysicalDisk | ? Model -like "*250*" | ? DeviceID -ne 0

7. The disks are not in the S2D pool now, so we should be able to run Get-Disk and see them right?

Get-Disk

My results show the OS drive and the S2D volume for the ClusterPerformanceHistory.

[OS Drive and ClusterPerformanceHistory Drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2bz0.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: does not work on s2d 2019, I got "cache out of date"

Answer (score 1):

Here’s the single step left to do:

```
Set-ClusterStorageSpacesDirectDisk -PhysicalDisk $disk -CanBeClaimed:$false
```